# Connexion to ftp server with android

Tags: android, ftp, libraries

i'm newbie on android,
I'm trying to upload file from sdcard to ftp server using android, the code seems to be correct. While debbuging it says that my connet and upload functions to the server can not access the classes given by org.appache.commons.net (no source found in those classes), knowing that i have this org.appache.commons.net  jar in the libs foldre, the project build path and the user libraries. 
Should i use another librarie or, is there any other work to do ?

The code

```
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,String password, int port){
try {
mFTPClient = new FTPClient();  
mFTPClient.connect(host, port);
mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode(); 
if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
// login using username & password
boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
Log.w("into the ftpUpload","!!");
mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
Log.w("into the ftpUpload","!!");
return status;
}
} catch(Exception e) {
Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host );
}
                return false;}
```

call this methode in another class using 
    FtpClient FTP = new FtpClient(); 
    FTP.ftpConnect("*.*.*.*", "*", "*", 21);

I'm doing it juste like several posts propose it, concerning the lib i added the org.apache.commons.net jar to the lib file and to the java build path.. 
The exception is given exactly here: mFTPClient.connect(host, port); (btw there are no logs).. Does anybody have an idea what can be the problem with that? I tried lot of codes that works for others but it fail to connect to the ftp server every time. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Without seeing the code and the error, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Ok, i've added the concerned code. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: it was about giving the local host address 127.0.0.1 on the host parameter in ftpConnect function, the ip @ of the machine shoud be given in its place.